# Neovim shows python related error after installing semshi

Tags: neovim, macos, python

I'm currently in the process of setting up my configuration for my Neovim environment and I'm struggling with some Python related issues.

I'm on macOS with `nvim 0.9.4`, installed over `brew` (if that should be relevant). I created a virtualevn with `pyenv` (the path to that env is `/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin/`). I'm using vim-plug as a plugin manager. My configuration looks like this

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set number
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set smartindent


call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'

" Telescope
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.4' }

" Theme
Plug 'daltonmenezes/aura-theme', { 'rtp': 'packages/neovim' }

" Language server
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'neoclide/coc-python', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}
Plug 'pappasam/coc-jedi', { 'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn build', 'branch': 'main' }
Plug 'neoclide/coc-tabnine', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}
Plug 'neoclide/coc-yaml', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}
Plug 'neoclide/coc-json', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}

" Python
Plug 'numirias/semshi', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }    " Syntax Highlighting
Plug 'averms/black-nvim', {'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins'}    " Black formatter

" Debugging
Plug 'puremourning/vimspector'
call plug#end()
" Theme
colorscheme aura-dark-soft-text

let g:python3_host_prog = '/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin/python3'

" Find files using Telescope command-line sugar.
nnoremap <leader>ff <cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fg <cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fb <cmd>Telescope buffers<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fh <cmd>Telescope help_tags<cr>

" use Ctrl+Space to trigger completion and navigate to the next complete item
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
" Use <Tab> and <S-Tab> to navigate the completion list:
inoremap <expr> <Tab> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<S-Tab>"

" Vimspector
" mnemonic 'di' = 'debug inspect' (pick your own, if you prefer!)
" for normal mode - the word under the cursor
nmap <Leader>di <Plug>VimspectorBalloonEval
" for visual mode, the visually selected text
xmap <Leader>di <Plug>VimspectorBalloonEval

runtime coc-init.vim
```

After installing [`semshi`](https://github.com/numirias/semshi), I started seeing an error message when I open a Python file in `nvim`, i.e.

```
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: Error executing lua: ...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/n
vim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: BufNewFile Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>23_filetype_changed, line 4: Vim:E492: Not
an editor command:             Semshi enable
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        ...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function <...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function <...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function <...brew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
```

Running `:checkhealth` reveals

```
coc: health#coc#check

- OK nvim version satisfied
- OK Environment check passed
- WARNING pyx command not work, some extensions may fail to work, checkout ":help pythonx"
- WARNING Install pynvim by command: `pip install pynvim --upgrade`
- OK Javascript bundle build/index.js found
- OK Service started
```

and `:checkhealth provider`

```
provider: health#provider#check

Python 3 provider (optional) ~
- pyenv: Path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.31/libexec/pyenv
- pyenv: $PYENV_ROOT is not set. Infer from `pyenv root`.
- pyenv: Root: /Users/name/.pyenv
- Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin/python3"
- Executable: /Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin/python3
- Python version: 3.12.0
- pynvim version: 0.5.0dev0
- OK Latest pynvim is installed.

Python virtualenv ~
- OK no $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

and last but not least `:echo has('python3')` returns `0`.

So I first assumed that I was missing the `pynvim` package and that my Neovim had no built-in python... But

- the `pyenv` environment has `pynvim` installed and up-to-date (I triple checked)
- whenever I open a clean nvim session (i.e. empty, no files) and do `:echo has('python3')` I get `1`.

If anybody sees something that would explain this, I would really appreciate the input. Thanks.

### Update

After @VivianDeSmet's answer, I updated my `pynvim` package in the virtual environment, but the issue still persists. `:checkhealth` no gives

```
Python 3 provider (optional) ~
- pyenv: Path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.31/libexec/pyenv
- pyenv: $PYENV_ROOT is not set. Infer from `pyenv root`.
- pyenv: Root: /Users/name/.pyenv
- Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/default/bin/python3"
- Executable: /Users/name/.pyenv/versions/default/bin/python3
- Python version: 3.12.0
- pynvim version: 0.5.0dev0
- OK Latest pynvim is installed.

Python virtualenv ~
- $VIRTUAL_ENV is set to: /Users/iilak/.pyenv/versions/default
- Python version: 3.12.0
- OK $VIRTUAL_ENV provides :!python.
```

Eror message when opening a Python file stays the same and behaviour as well (i.e. opening non-python files and running `:echo has('python3')` returns `1`, but for Python files `0`)

Answer (score 1):

The current released version of [pynvim](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim) doesn't support Python 3.12 see [this](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim/issues/538#issuecomment-1799527328) issue.

You can solve that problem by installing the trunk version of [pynvim](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim) to solve the problem:

```
pip install 'pynvim @ git+https://github.com/neovim/pynvim'
```

Remark: Neovim potentially uses two installations (determined by the pair: (`sys.version`, `sys.path`)) of Python:

1. The one that is embedded (the one used by the `:py3` command), that you can determine by running the commands: `:py3 print(sys.version)` `:py3 print(sys.path)`
2. The one that is determined by the value of the variable `g:python3_host_prog`

I suspect you need that both have `pynvim` installed or that at least the first has `pynvim` installed (you can verify that by running `:py3 import pynvim`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated my `pynvim` package to `0.5.0dev` but the problem persists. I update my questions with the new `:checkhealth`, status, but bscly. everything seems okey to me. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems the Python embedding is not working yet. What is the result of `:py3 print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38775/23502) could help you figuring out what is not working.

Comment: Running `:py3 print(sys.version)` in a clean nvim gives `3.12.0 (main, Nov  5 2023, 14:26:43) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)]` (opening a python file and running the same give also the same result).

Comment: Regarding the answer you linked to: 64 bit version, Python3 support should work since the above `:py3` command is executed and shows the correct output... The issue really only appear when opening a Python File... Really weird

Comment: What os the result of: ` :checkhealth` after the new installation? I suspect the Python installation used by the embedded python not to be the same as the one used by the provider.

Comment: What is the result of the Neovim command `:py3 import pynvim`?

Comment: What is the result of the Neovim command `:py3 print(sys.path)`?

Comment: `:py3 import pynvim; print(pynvim.__file__) -> /Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pynvim/__init_
_.py` and the path gives
`['/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python312.zip', '/Users/name/.pyen
v/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12', '/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/p
ython3.12/lib-dynload', '/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.12/
site-packages', '_vim_path_']`

Comment: Regarding the `checkhealth`, you can see it in my question under Update. Can't post it here since it is too long for a comment..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I must admit I'm lost :-). Just by curiosity what is the result of `:pyx print(sys.version)` and `:pyx import pynvim`?

Comment: The first one gives `3.12.0 (main, Nov  5 2023, 14:26:43) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)]` and the second one does not output anything (but there is also no error..). Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciated you taking the time!